# C# get also the key from parsing substring from string

Tags: c#

I would like to refactor my method. I also need to get which value was first? So which anyOf? Is it possible to get it from here?

Example:

```
List<string> anyOf = new List<string>(){"at", "near", "by", "above"};
string source = "South Branch Raritan River near High Bridge at NJ"

public static int IndexOfAny(this string source, IEnumerable<string> anyOf, StringComparison stringComparisonType = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
{
    var founds = anyOf
        .Select(sub => source.IndexOf(sub, stringComparisonType))
        .Where(i => i >= 0);
    return founds.Any() ? founds.Min() : -1;
}
```

I would like to get back what is first in string. "near" or "at".

Comment: Your code is inefficient because both `.Any()` and `.Min()` will re-execute the Linq expression from scratch.

Comment: Perhaps rewriting your method using a simple foreach loop would make it more efficient, more clear and more readable.

Comment: And what "key" are you referring to? Parse what, exactly? You haven't told us what kinds of string values are inside `source` or `anyOf`.

Comment: Sorry updated my question

Comment: Are you looking for a trie algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
public static (int index, string? firstMatch) IndexOfAny(this string source, IEnumerable<string> anyOf, StringComparison stringComparisonType = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
{
    return anyOf
        .Select(s => (Index: source.IndexOf(s, stringComparisonType), String: s))
        .Where(x => x.Index >= 0)
        .DefaultIfEmpty((-1, null))
        .First();
}
```

Comment: I think `(int index, string firstMatch)?` makes more sense than `(int index, string? firstMatch)` - that way you can return `null` to represent no-result which is clearer than having to document that `index == -1` is possible, and also avoids nullable warnings about `string? firstMatch`.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resist creating a more efficient implementation.

[Working here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nooy3q)

Whilst this looks more complicated, its better because,

It allocates only,

- an array for the valid search terms,
- a array of indices for each search term and,
- an array of lengths for each search term.

The source text is enumerated only once and, if a match is found,
that loop will exit early.

Additionally, the code incorporates parameter checking which you'll want as extension methods should be resusable.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int IndexOfAny<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> targets,
        IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        // Parameter Handling
        comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(targets);
        
        var clean = targets
            .Where(t => t != null)
            .Select(t => t.ToArray())
            .Where(t => t.Length > 0)
            .ToArray();
        
        if (clean.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                $"'{nameof(targets)}' does not contain a valid search sequence");
        }
        
        // Prep
        var lengths = clean.Select(t => t.Length).ToArray();
        var indices = clean.Select(_ => 0).ToArray();
        int i = 0;
        
        // Process
        foreach(var t in source)
        {
            i++;
            for(var j = 0; j < clean.Length; j++)
            {
                var index = indices[j];
                if (comparer.Equals(clean[j][index], t))
                {
                    index += 1;
                    if (index == lengths[j])
                    {
                        return i - lengths[j];
                    }
                    
                    indices[j] = index;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (index != 0)
                    {
                        indices[j] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
    
    public static int IndexOfAny(
        this string source,
        IEnumerable<string> targets,
        StringComparer comparer = null)
    {
        comparer = comparer ?? StringComparer.Ordinal;
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(targets);
        return source.ToCharArray().IndexOfAny(
            targets.Select(t => t.ToCharArray()),
            new CharComparerAdapter(comparer));
    }
}

public class CharComparerAdapter : IEqualityComparer<char>
{
    private StringComparer Comparer { get; }
    
    public CharComparerAdapter(StringComparer comparer)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(comparer);
        Comparer = comparer;
    }
    
    public bool Equals(char left, char right)
    {
        return Comparer.Equals(left.ToString(), right.ToString());
    }
    
    public int GetHashCode(char v)
    {
        return v;
    }
}
```